How can I use satisfies on module exports?
I want to use satifies to ensure module exports meet the criteria of a certain type.
For example, types.ts:
export type Route = {
  pathname: string;
  handler: Promise<Response>;
}

Then in a route module:
import type { Route } from './types.ts';

export const pathname = '/test'

export const handler = async () => {
  return new Response('test');
}

this satisfies Route

I get this error:

Type 'undefined' does not satisfy the expected type 'Route'.

Is it possible to do something like this?
I tried using this, self, etc...nothing works.
Edit: is this the closest I will get?:
import type { Route } from './types.ts';

const pathname = 'test'

const handler = async () => {
  return new Response('test');
}

export default {pathname, handler} satisfies Route


const route: Route = { pathname, handler }; export default route; No need to abuse the satisfies keyword here.

If you want to use satisfies just use it as you are. But your handler type is wrong:

import type { Route } from "./types";
/*
  export type Route = {
    pathname: string;
    handler: () => Promise<Response>;
  };
*/

const pathname = "test";

const handler = async () => {
  return new Response("test");
};

export default { pathname, handler } satisfies Route;



This is verbatim the code that is presented in the second half of OP's question. What value are you trying to add?
